# Dovecot: How to unset namespace configuration from dovecot.conf in conf.d/99-custom.conf?

Tags: dovecot

My `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` that is shipped with the Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) distro has a namespace section:

```
namespace inbox { 
  ...
  mailbox Sent {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I need to remove this whole section from the configuration, but I need to do this in a file such as `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-custom.conf` because I want this modification to be stable against automatic updates of `dovecot.conf` shipped by the distro.

How do I "unset" an earlier namespace configuration at a later point in `99-custom.conf`? The desired behavior is the configuration of dovecot that results from the namespace passage completely removed in `dovecot.conf`. Basically, I would like to achieve this without modifying `dovecot.conf`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `dovecot.conf` has already been modified.

The `dovecot-core` package of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS uses `ucf` to handle configuration files, so a copy of the distribution's current "factory default" `dovecot.conf` should be at `/usr/share/dovecot/dovecot.conf` on your system. The same should be true for essentially all the Dovecot configuration files supplied by the package.
(There's a fairly substantial bit of scripting to handle these configuration files in the `postinst` script of the package.)

I've just downloaded and extracted [dovecot-core of 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dovecot-core) and checked the default configuration file. It has no namespace entries at all, and in fact has a comment that confirms that there is supposed to be no active namespace nor plugin settings in it by default:

```
# Default values are shown for each setting, it's not required to uncomment
# those. These are exceptions to this though: No sections (e.g. namespace {})
# or plugin settings are added by default, they're listed only as examples.
```

`ucf` attempts to preserve local configuration changes, so it is possible that your namespace configuration is in fact either something that's been done locally, or a remnant from a yet earlier version that has been preserved just fine so far, if you've upgraded this system from an earlier major release.

On my Debian 10 system with Dovecot in use, `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` is 100% identical to `/usr/share/dovecot/dovecot.conf`. Neither of them contains any namespace sections.

You should probably run `diff -u /usr/share/dovecot/dovecot.conf /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` to find the differences between the distribution's "factory default" configuration and your current one. Perhaps it's just the namespace declaration that has been placed in `dovecot.conf` instead of `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-custom.conf` back when the system was new and you didn't know of a better way.

Or perhaps you'll find that there are a lot of differences, probably because the current `dovecot.conf` has been carried over from an older release? In that case, it would seem you've incurred some technical debt over at least one release cycle, and today might be a good day to start getting rid of it, by carefully picking apart the differences and moving local customizations to `99-custom.conf`.

---

When using hosting control panel such as Plesk, there may be major differences in configuration. [Plesk documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/mail/using-other-mail-server-software.72350/) says this about using Dovecot:

> Due to high diversity of Dovecot versions in OS vendor repositories, we build our own packages. Many Dovecot features that do not make much sense in Plesk context are left out (the provided version is built without their support).

So you may be getting a Dovecot configuration that is effectively partially hard-coded and/or restricted in other ways too. It seems that the Plesk-provided Dovecot configuration may be optimized for being administered mostly or exclusively through the hosting control panel.

However, with the `dpkg` packaging system, there is a feature you can use in situations like this.

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

This command will cause the package management to rename the existing `dovecot.conf` file to `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.distrib` **and it will keep redirecting any future versions of the package-provided file to the new name** so that the actual `dovecot.conf` is no longer managed by packages at all. 
After that command, you can/must run:

```
sudo cp /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.distrib /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

and then you can manipulate `dovecot.conf` as you please, secure in the knowledge that any changes the package management would apply will go into `dovecot.conf.distrib` instead. Effectively, you have told `dpkg` that "when a package talks about `dovecot.conf`, it actually means `dovecot.conf.distrib` instead."

Please use this knowledge wisely, as it also allows you to shoot yourself in the foot in spectacular ways, if used without due consideration.

Comment: Thanks. I think the answer to the riddle is that I'm using Plesk and the adapted Dovecot shipped with Plesk has this namespace configuration in dovecot.conf to enable switching to Courier. So my question remains: Is there a way to unset a namespace configuration that was implemented earlier in the stack of config files.